# Как написать sql запрос на вывод абсолютно всех данных, сгруппированных по столбцу

Tags: mysql, sql

У меня есть таблица links с полями kink и size. Поле link хранит ссылку на файл, а поле size размер этого файла. Часто бывает такое, что размер файла повторяется в таблице по несколько раз. Мне нужно вывести абсолютно все данные из поля link и size + столбец, который показывает сколько раз size встречается в таблице.
Например вывод может быть таким:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно сделать такой результат? Я пробовал писать такой запрос "SELECT link, size, COUNT(size) as recur from links GROUP BY size HAVING recur > 1" (здесь вывожу только если размер больше 1). Но результат не тот. Значения просто группируются по полю size.

Comment: Тут нужен не `GROUP BY`, a `COUNT() OVER ()`.

Comment: MySQL не поддерживает оконные функции. Может можно подзапросом как-то

Comment: *MySQL не поддерживает оконные функции.* Во блин! а мужики-то не знают... MySQL 8, который поддерживает CTE и оконные функции, вышел семь лет назад - см. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html Если у тебя до сих пор древняя версия, то пора бы уже и обновиться...

Comment: Существует и тривиальный способ получить нужные данные.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT a.link, a.size, b.recur
FROM links a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT size, COUNT(size) AS recur
    FROM links 
    GROUP BY size
) b ON a.size = b.size
```

[Пример.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0fb5fca6/2)

Условие отбора можно добавить по необходимости.